# Direct IP access not allowed cloudflare in nginx proxy server

Tags: nginx, proxy, server

I have one site in openshift rhc ,So i want to make one reserve Proxy with nginx software in Openshift Rhc servers, which from this server have access to many other server with nginx so i configured my nginx server by this kind of configuration :

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;
error_log {{OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}}/app-root/logs/nginx_error.log debug;

pid        {{NGINX_DIR}}/logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;
    #access_log $OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR/access.log main;
    port_in_redirect off;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  165;

    gzip  on;

    upstream frontends {
        #server pr4ss.tk;
        #server 222.66.115.233:80 weight=1;
        server {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:8081 ;

    }
    upstream frontends2 {
        server google.com;
        #server 222.66.115.233:80 weight=1;
        #server {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:8081 ;

    }
    upstream index {

        server free-papers.elasa.ir weight=1;
        server diy4tornado-tornado4ss.rhcloud.com weight=2;

    }
    upstream comment {
        server vb2-fishsmarkets.rhcloud.com;
        #server  community.elasa.ir;
    }

    server {
        listen      {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:{{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_PORT}};
        server_name  {{OPENSHIFT_GEAR_DNS}} www.{{OPENSHIFT_GEAR_DNS}};
        root {{OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}};


        set_real_ip_from {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}};
        real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location /main {
            root   {{OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}};
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
            autoindex_localtime on;

            #proxy_set_header Authorization base64_encoding_of_"user:password";
            #proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

        }
        location ~* ^/(.*) {
            #proxy_set_header Host vb2-fishsmarkets.rhcloud.com;
            #proxy_redirect  http://vb2-fishsmarkets.rhcloud.com/ http://diy-elasa2.rhcloud.com/;
            #proxy_pass http://comment/$1$is_args$args;
            proxy_pass http://index/$1$is_args$args;
        }
        location ^~ /admincp {
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^/admincp/(.*)$ /index.php?routestring=admincp/$1 last;
                }
                proxy_set_header Host vb2-fishsmarkets.rhcloud.com;
            proxy_redirect  http://vb2-fishsmarkets.rhcloud.com/ http://diy-elasa2.rhcloud.com/;
            proxy_pass http://comment/$1$is_args$args;
        }
        location /www {
            #root   {{OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}};
            index  index.html index.htm;

            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
            autoindex_localtime on;

            #proxy_set_header Authorization base64_encoding_of_"user:password";
            #proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://frontends;
        }
        location /categories {
            #root   {{OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}};
            index  index.html index.htm;

            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
            autoindex_localtime on;

            #proxy_set_header Authorization base64_encoding_of_"user:password";
            #proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://frontends2;
        }
        location /index {
            #root   {{OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}};
            index  index.html index.htm;

            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
            autoindex_localtime on;
            # an HTTP header important enough to have its own Wikipedia entry:
            #   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;


            # enable this if you forward HTTPS traffic to unicorn,
            # this helps Rack set the proper URL scheme for doing redirects:
            # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            # pass the Host: header from the client right along so redirects
            # can be set properly within the Rack application
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

            # we don't want nginx trying to do something clever with
            # redirects, we set the Host: header above already.
            proxy_redirect off;

            # set "proxy_buffering off" *only* for Rainbows! when doing
            # Comet/long-poll/streaming.  It's also safe to set if you're using
            # only serving fast clients with Unicorn + nginx, but not slow
            # clients.  You normally want nginx to buffer responses to slow
            # clients, even with Rails 3.1 streaming because otherwise a slow
            # client can become a bottleneck of Unicorn.
            #
            # The Rack application may also set "X-Accel-Buffering (yes|no)"
            # in the response headers do disable/enable buffering on a
            # per-response basis.
            # proxy_buffering off;






            client_max_body_size       10m;
            client_body_buffer_size    128k;

            proxy_connect_timeout      10;
            proxy_send_timeout         5;
            proxy_read_timeout         3600;

            proxy_buffer_size          4k;
            proxy_buffers              4 132k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size    264k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 164k;
            proxy_pass http://index;            


            #proxy_set_header Authorization base64_encoding_of_"user:password";
            #proxy_pass_header Server;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }



        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   {{OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP}}:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl                  on;
    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

I used **Upstream index**:

```
upstream index {

        server free-papers.elasa.ir weight=1;
        server diy4tornado-tornado4ss.rhcloud.com weight=2;


    }
```

but when i use this configuration ( with cloudflare or rhc server) i get this error from cloudflare:

> Direct IP access not allowed cloudflare

So what is proper configuration for nginx or Apache server software for this kind of servers.

Thanks a lot for your attentions.

Answer (score -1):

i found the answer:

```
 gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain application/xml application/javascript text/javas$
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_http_version 1.1;


    upstream comment {
                    #server vb-fishsmarkets.rhcloud.com;
                    #server vb.elasa.ir;
                    #server  vb-elasa3.rhcloud.com ;
                    #server vb2-fishsmarkets.rhcloud.com;
                    #server forums.fishsmarket.tk;
                    #server  community.elasa.ir;
                    #server free-papers.elasa.ir;
                    #server  diy4tornado-tornado4ss.rhcloud.com weight=1;
                    server free-papers.elasa.ir weight=1;
            }

  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=30r/m;
        limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one2:10m rate=1r/m;
        limit_req_zone $http_x_forwarded_for zone=one3:10m rate=1r/m;
        proxy_cache_path  /tmp  levels=1:2    keys_zone=RUBYGEMS:10m
                                       inactive=24h  max_size=1g;
    server {
        listen        127.6.145.1:8080;
        server_name  diy-elasa2.rhcloud.com community.elasa.ir ;

        #charset koi8-r;
```

and :

```
     location ~* ^/(.*) {
                #root   html;
                #index  index.html index.htm;


                            #proxy_set_header Host  vb2-fishsmarkets.rhcloud.com;
                            proxy_set_header Host  free-papers.elasa.ir;
                            #proxy_redirect  http://vb2-fishsmarkets.rhcloud.com/ h$
                            #proxy_redirect  http://fm.elasa.ir/ http://community.e$
                            proxy_pass http://comment/$1$is_args$args;
                            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                #proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;

 sub_filter 'http://fm.elasa.ir/'   'http://community.el$
                        sub_filter_once on;

                        proxy_set_header X-outside-url $scheme://$host;
                        #proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;





                        proxy_cache            RUBYGEMS;
                        proxy_cache_valid      200  1d;
                        proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header upd$
                               http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

                        proxy_http_version 1.1;





                        proxy_cache            RUBYGEMS;
                        proxy_cache_valid      200  1d;
                        proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header upd$
                               http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';

          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;


                        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                        proxy_redirect off;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded$


 client_max_body_size 100M;
                        client_body_buffer_size 1m;
                        proxy_intercept_errors on;
                        proxy_buffering on;
                        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
                        proxy_buffers 256 16k;
                        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                        proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
                        #proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
                        proxy_read_timeout 300;
                }
```

Important things is proxy header Host:

```
proxy_set_header Host  free-papers.elasa.ir;
```